# What is best enterprise for IT Consultant in US?

Tags: usa, working, salary, culture

I'm IT consultant graduated from French public engineering school, I work currently as Cloud Solutions Architect in Paris and plan to make my career in New Technologies (AI, Robotics, Cloud/DevOps, ...)

I plan to move to US as the first Tech hub in the world in order to discover culture and earn significant experience.

I need to know what's the best enterprise profil for IT professional regarding salary and work environment ?

- Large Company OR Start-up/Scale-up ?
- Consulting firm OR internal employee at industrial compagny ?
- Working in New York OR Los Angeles?

Also,

- What are relevant job boards including sponsorship-friendly compagnies ?
- Is there a reliable source of information about US salary per profil ?

I recently heard about "1 million talents for 2025" program, is this effective?

Please, answer should be accurate, fact-based (press articles) and considers salary and best work environment.

Thanks in advance for your answer.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **only** thing you should be asking yourself is "who's going to sponsor my visa".

Anything else is: (a) subjective, and depends on your own preferences which we know nothing about, and (b) irrelevant to this forum.

You seem to be assuming that the US is similar to France in its workspace landscape. It is not.

The difference between Los Angeles and New York is not only 6 hours flight, but also significant cultural differences, different laws and regulations, different conventions and even different accents. Consider, for example, Paris and Montreal.

There's also no such thing as "US salary". You can earn the same amount of money in Lincoln, NE and in San Francisco, CA, but you may end up being considered "wealthy" in Lincoln, while living barely paycheck to paycheck in San Francisco. Same salary, technically same country, vastly different costs of living.

So first you'll either need to find a visa sponsor and determine location based on that, or determine location and then start looking for sponsors there - based on what's important to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand that there no difference between parameters (in my question) for US labor market offers, it's either way to work for large company or start-up, as contractor or internal employee, no difference is made for salary. Except regions which make local expenses, not salary, cheap or expensive.

Comment: @CloudRock yes, basically, that's the situation. The US market is not as rigid as the French, and there's much less emphasis on "tradition" or "size" than there is on "capabilities" and "market worth". You can get a significantly different offer depending on your interview performance, on whether or not you have competing offers, and whether or not you have some specific knowledge or expertise the employer is currently looking for. The size of the employer rarely makes significant difference.

Comment: It's clear. Thanks again.